# Bootstrap Validator to validate length of field correct syntax

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I'm trying to validate the string's length with Bootstrap Validator. Unfortunately, the JavaScript does not work. I'm thinking maybe a syntax error.

HTML :

```
    <form id="ordertracking" role="form">
        <div style="margin-bottom: 12px" class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><strong>@</strong></span>
        <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Email">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-barcode"></i></span>
            <input id="login-password" type="text" class="form-control" name="customerNum" placeholder="Customer #">       
    </form>
```

JS:

```
 $('#ordertracking').bootstrapValidator({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            email: {
                validators: {
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 5,
                        max: 50,
                        message: 'The full email must be less than 50 characters'
                    }
                }
            },
            customerNum: {
                validators: {
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 4,
                        max: 6,
                        message: 'The customer number has to be 5 or 6 digits'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Link to Codepen: http://codepen.io/Delano83/pen/bwQZbB

I've been knocking my head on this for two hours so any suggestions is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't included the Library:

Add this to your head section below all the other scripts and it should work.

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"></script>`

if you check the console you will see this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootstrapValidator is not a function
```

That made me realise the library was not being loaded correctly.